# i want to learn how to animate

Tags: animation, free

i would like a free online website that is easy to use, I've looked all over the internet but kind find anything that is the right one, i would like to draw them my self.

Answer (score 1):

Take a bunch of papers, hole punch them. Take a ringbinder and rip the holding mechanism out and mount it on a flat surface (better yet take 2). Put the papers trough the holder and start drawing. When when done, place a a camera on a tripod and shoot each image.

Anyway if you want to work digitally then every drawing application will do the job, just save the the individual images with a separate number after the name like for example animation_001.png then collate them to a video file. Yes that means any application would work. Even paint, tough having layers could help quite much.

Animation is a time consuming process so it really pans out to invest in the infrastructure. So consider something like:

- Krita ([animation Beta](https://krita.org/en/item/krita-2-9-animation-edition-beta-released/)) <- free
- Adobe animate
- Toonboom harmony
- Synfig Studio <- free

Note that paying for animation software is paying itself back quite quickly as saving one minute drawing a frame translates to 12-25 saved hours per finished minute of animation.